# Catenation of two commands to a file and email output

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, ksh

```
#!/bin/ksh


#HOSTS format:
HOSTS="xxxx.xxx.xxx.xx-ACCOUNT" 

FILE=/home/angela/list.txt #list will be saved on list.txt

date > $FILE
echo >> $FILE

for host in $HOSTS; do
  ip=$(echo $host|cut -d '-' -f 1)
  title=$(echo $host|cut -d '-' -f 2)
 lsuser -a login ALL | grep '=true$'  | awk '{ print $1 }'   >/tmp/delta 2>/dev/null

  echo "$title instance" >> $FILE
  perl -e 'print "=" x 65,"\n"' >>$FILE

#we filter through unwanteduser.list to remove unwanted users

  cat /tmp/delta|grep -wvf /home/angela/unwanteduser.list|sort >> $FILE
  echo >> $FILE
done

rm -f /tmp/delta


mailx -r From-account-server-no-reply@xyz.com -s "List of active Users and Locked users" angela@xyz.com <  "$FILE"
```

i am trying to add `lsuser -a login ALL | grep '=false$'  | awk '{ print $1 }'`

list of locked account to above script and send email with list of active users and locked users

Present script gives me this

```
Wed Oct 21 10:36:51 CDT 2015

Account instance
=================================================================
john
alex
raven
max
```

I want to accomplish this

```
Wed Oct 21 10:36:51 CDT 2015

list of Active users

Account instance
=================================================================

john
alex
raven
max

list of Locked users

Account instance
=================================================================
joe
tracy
karen
ben
```

So far i was able to list only active users.
I tried below script just got the date without any output , however it does not meet the format im trying to accomplish

```
 #!/bin/ksh



(
 date
 echo
 for host in $HOSTS; do
     echo "${host/*-} instance"cat
     perl -e 'print "=" x 65,"\n"'
 lsuser -a login ALL | awk '/=true$/ { print $1 }' | grep -wvf /home/angela/unwanted.list
lsuser -a login ALL | awk '/=false$/ { print $1 }' | grep -wvf /home/angela/unwanted.list
echo
 done
) | mailx -r From-account-server-no-reply@xyz.com -s "List of active Users and Locked users" angela@xyz.com
```

Comment: This looks a lot like you're running in AIX instead of Linux (as the tag currently says) - is that right?

Comment: @Jeff Schaller yes I run this on both, no difference in results

Comment: @Jeff Schaller  yes . /etc/passwd  which I tried earlier

Comment: @Jeff Schaller  updated the script

Comment: That use of `/tmp/temp` allows for arbitrary file deletions against the user running the script. A local security flaw, in other words. Please instead use `mktemp(1)` or first `mkdir /tmp/somedir` and only if that passes then write files under `/tmp/somedir`.

Comment: Is this the actual script? Or actual output? Because the script filters through an unwanted list and then pipes to sort, but your sample output usernames are not sorted.

Comment: @@Jeff Schaller its actual./etc/passwd had some dummpy users which are not real user. All dummy users are added to unwanted list  .whatever output im getting from lsuser is filtered through unwanted list to give the real user output   for example: users like daemon,ssh ect...

Comment: @Jeff Schaller /etc/passwd had some dummy users which are not real user. All dummy users are added to unwanted list .whatever output im getting from lsuser is filtered through unwanted list to give the real user output for example: users like daemon,ssh ect...

Comment: Do you really get *unsorted* user output from your script? And is this really being run in Linux?  BTW, changing "/tmp/temp" to "/tmp/delta" doesn't make the script any more secure. AIX lacks a nice mktemp user-level interface; I ended up writing one for myself.

Comment: @ Jeff Schaller yes I have tried it , it sorts out, filters through the unwanted list, removes unwanted user and sends the right one.   How do I adjust it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mail the output of a number of different commands together in one message, don't bother with temp files, group the commands and simply use a pipe:

```
(
 date
 echo
 for host in $HOSTS; do
     echo "${host/*-} instance"
     perl -e 'print "=" x 65,"\n"
     lsuser -a login ALL | awk '/=true$/ { print $1 }' | grep -wvf /home/angela/unwanteduser.list
     echo
 done
) | mailx -r From-account-server-no-reply@xyz.com -s "List of active Users and Locked users" angela@xyz.com
```

The `(` .. `)` thing runs the command between the brackets in a separate subshell process, so all its standard output can be piped together.

The filtering can be done at the point the data is being generated, instead of at the end.

If you're using `awk` anyway, the you can leave out the `grep` part of the pipeline as `awk` is perfectly capable of selecting what lines to process itself. This needs one less process which is more efficient.

I've also done away with the temp "title" variable, using patterm substitution to get rid of the IP address (replaces `*-` with nothing).

I'd spell out the 65 `=` characters, as invoking perl to do this leads to quite a substantial overhead. You won't notice much running just this script, but if you get into the habit and and some time write such a script that gets executed multiple times a second, then you *will* notice the difference.

Comment: but i have to filter both the commands with unwanted list where it get rids of  dummy users

Comment: forwarding the output to tmp because i want to filter the users with a list contains dummy users

Comment: I would filter the list at the point the list is generated (i.e. after the `awk` command, add the pipe to `grep` there), not when you're mailing. That way it becomes immediately clear that you're doing that. Also a pet peeve I have: don't do `cat file | grep whatever`, that creates an unnecessary process and pipe when a simple `grep whatever file` will do. Use `< file grep whatever` if you must :-)

Comment: can you please adjust the script what you are talking about, still confused

Comment: I've edited my answer, I've also replaced your grep | awk with just awk :)

Comment: My answer now is quite complete. If you also need a list of locked users, you'll need to duplicate the 4 lines inside the brackets and modify to select those users.

Comment: can i add the other command to it  lsuser -a login ALL | grep '=false$'  | awk '{ print $1 }'   this gives me locked users. like the format mentioned above

Comment: @ got synatx error   0403-057 Syntax error at line 11 : `'' is not matched

Comment: #!/bin/ksh



(
 date
 echo
 for host in $HOSTS; do
     echo "${host/*-} instance"cat
     perl -e 'print "=" x 65,"\n"'
 lsuser -a login ALL | awk '/=true$/ { print $1 }' | grep -wvf /home/angela/unwanted.list
lsuser -a login ALL | awk '/=false$/ { print $1 }' | grep -wvf /home/muneer/unwanted.list
echo
 done
) | mailx -r From-account-server-no-reply@xyz.com -s "List of active Users and Locked users" angela@xyz.com

Comment: There's a stray `cat` on the `echo` line, besides that the `HOSTS` variable got lost in the edit; apart from that I don't see why the error message should be given. Try it on linux, perhaps the `ksh` on AIX doesn't understand the `${host/*-}` thing (or leave that out for the time being).

Comment: is there any way we can add  lsuser -a login ALL | grep '=false$'  | awk '{ print $1 }' in orginial script i have created because it gives me right format needed

Comment: tried without hosts errored out